# Find the area of the region containing the points inside the ellipse $2x^2+y^2-2xy-4x=0$ but outside the ellipse $2x^2+y^2+2xy-4x=0$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, area

Find the area of the region containing the points inside the ellipse

$2x^2+y^2-2xy-4x=0$

but outside the ellipse

$2x^2+y^2+2xy-4x=0$.

I was able to find the required area using integration. But it is required to find the area without using integration. Is there a property of ellipse that i am missing.

Comment: Can you use that area is $\pi a b$ where $a,b$ are the lengths of the semimajor and semiminor axes of the ellipse?

Comment: There are formulas for the area between a line segment and an elliptical arc. Take a look at "https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/AreaIntersectingEllipses.pdf." Of course, it is unclear if this qualifies as not using integration, as the formulas do not come from the void...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem amounts at finding the area $A_\text{elliptical segment}$ of that segment of ellipse $e$ of equation
$$
2x^2+y^2+2xy−4x=0
$$
(blue in figure below) lying above the $x$-axis.
The area of the whole region mentioned in the question is twice that area.

From the equation one readily finds that $e$ intersects the $x$-axis at
$A=(0,0)$ and $B=(2,0)$. Moreover, for $x=0$ and $x=4$ we get a single value of $y$, thus $e$ has vertical tangents at $A$ and $(4,-4)$, and its center is their midpoint $O=(2,-2)$. The line through $O$ parallel to $x$-axis intersects $e$ at
$H=(2-\sqrt2,-2)$, $I=(2+\sqrt2,-2)$.

If $M=(1,0)$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then line $OM$ intersects $e$ at points $E$, $F$ with horizontal tangent. Moreover, $OM$ meets at $T=(0,2)$ both tangents at $A$ and $B$, and we have:
$$
OM:OE=OE:OT,
$$
which projected onto $y$-axis gives
$$
4:(y_E+2)=(y_E+2):2,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
y_E=2\sqrt2-2.
$$
Let's now shear $e$ about the $x$-axis, to transform it to an ellipse $e'$ whose axes are parallel to cartesian axes (red in figure below). Note that the semi-major axis of $e'$ has a length
$$a'=y_E-y_O=2\sqrt2,$$
while the semi-minor axis has a length
$$b'=x_I-x_O=\sqrt2.$$
Shearing preserves area, hence the area we want to compute is the same as that of the part of ellipse $e'$ lying above the $x$-axis.

Finally, we can stretch $e'$ perpendicular to $x$-axis by a factor $b'/a'=1/2$, to obtain a circle (green in the figure) with radius $b'$.
The area of the circular segment with base $AB$ lying above the $x$-axis can be easily computed as:
$$
A_\text{circular segment}={\pi\over2}-1.
$$
To get the area of the elliptical segment we need only un-stretch $A_\text{circular segment}$ multiplying it by a factor of $2$:
$$
A_\text{elliptical segment}={\pi}-2.
$$

[image]